Making sense of observations from experiment on a wheel

This question is based on the observations from this video: https://youtube.com/shorts/3p8mcDsIcEc?si=QHZSwPhZJz8gFJHg
Please help me explain by the use of the equations of motion why the system behaves as such.
I tried using
$$F = ma_G$$
And
$$M_G = I_G\alpha$$
But I am not able to make sense of how the three cases will differ and lead to the observations
In the image, R is the radius of the wheel, r is the crank arm, G is almost equal to the COM, I just assume the crank is 'massless'

Just consider the torque whith F gives relative to the point where the wheel touches the ground.

Thanks Trula, that helps.

You can use linear momentum balance and angular momentum balance about point G together to solve for the acceleration of point G (a_G) in terms of $r$, $R$, $m$, and $I^G$.  For r<R, you will get a_G >0 (rolls right), and for r>R, a_G < 0 (rolls left). For r=R, a_G=0, and the force from the ground acting on the cylinder is equal and opposite to F.  If F is big enough, the cylinder will slide right with the force of friction resisting motion equal to the coefficient of friction between the cylinder and the ground times the normal force at the contact point (equal to m*g).
However, you can find the way the cylinder rolls using other rigorous means as follows (images taken from a PowerPoint presentation I made.) The case I solved for is r<R (Ri<Ro in my equations).  In the solution for a_G below, you can see how its sign depends on the sign of the difference (Ro-Ri).




Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead.

I think the "no images" rule is overly rigid, especially considering that no one gets paid to spend their time posting answers to questions.  Especially not questions that have been answered in other places and other formats.  If the answer is good and clear, who cares?

@MarianoG people who use screen readers (e.g., blind people, internet scrapers) care. While sighted people can read those images just fine, there are plenty of people & robots who don't know what they say.


$~F_c~$ constraint force
The disc is instantaneous  rotating at  the contact point $~c$. thus the EOM
$$ I_c\,\dot\omega_y=F\,(r-R)\quad,
I_c=I_{\rm CM}+m\,R^2$$
from here
if $~r >R~$ the rotations of the disk is positive, $~\omega_y >0~$
if $~r < R~$ the rotations of the disk is negative $~\omega_y < 0~$
if $~r = R~$ the the  disk is not rotate  $~\omega_y=0~$
at this state you obtain a torque about the z axis that caused the
disk to rotate about the z axis
